# How do I stop the Skype dialpad from popping up?

Tags: macos, skype

Every time I do anything on Skype, open up a contact for chatting, or talking, or many other actions, the dialpad pops up:

[image]

It's particularly problematic when I start chatting, because I double click a contact, start typing and instead of sending a message, I'm dialling. It only happens in one of my two computers, both running the same version of MacOSX and Skype. On the computer with the problem it happened since I installed Skype.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling skype on the problem computer?

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling probably won't work, you'd have to remove `~/Library/Preferences/com.skype.skype.plist` as well to reset that. Check if that works. You can disable the dial pad window with the `Cmd-2` shortcut, but that won't be a permanent change, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem for the longest time now. What seemed to work for me was to delete every trace of Skype on my mac.

- Delete **Skype.app** from the **Applications** folder.
- Go to **~/Library/Preferences/** and delete **com.skype.skype.plist**.
- Go to **/Library/Preferences/** and delete **com.skype.skype.plist** from there too.
- Go to **~/Library/** and delete the **Skype** folder.
- Download and install **Skype 2.8** from http://download.skype.com/macosx/Skype_2.8.0.866.dmg.
- After installing, wait for it to automatically ask you to update using the built in updater from Skype. (**DO NOT** download it from a browser.)
- After updating, relaunch Skype. The first time you log in, the **Dial Pad** will show but if you close it and you quit again, it won't show the next time you open Skype.

Hope that helped for you. :)

Comment: I followed these steps but am still seeing the dial pad every time I open skype. I'm wondering if its a new bug in the latest version of Skype because the problem only seems to exist depending on which version I install.